# ExportSnapshot unable to load

Tags: java, hadoop, export, hbase

I'm trying to export a table from cluster1 to cluster2 using snapshots. However, cluster2 is not accessible from cluster1 so I can't do:

`bin/hbase class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.tool.ExportSnapshot -snapshot MySnapshot -copy-to hdfs://cluster2:8020/hbase -mappers 16`

However, I am able to export to hdfs as:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot snapshot_my_table -copy-to hdfs://cluster1/export
```

The above command creates the following dirs:

```
hdfs://cluster1/export/.hbase-snapshot  
hdfs://cluster1/export/archive
```

I copied the files under 'hdfs://cluster1/export/.hbase-snapshot/snapshot_my_table' to the local filesystem, then tar.gzip'ed them, and then scp'd them to cluster2 via another machine.

I unarchived them under `hdfs://cluster2/export/.hbase-snapshot/`

Then I logged into the hbase shell, and was able to see the snapshot via a list_snapshots.

However, when issuing the `clone_snapshot` command, I get:

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.CorruptedSnapshotException: Corrupted snapshot 'name: "snapshot_my_table"
table: "my_table"
creation_time: 1416346483927
type: FLUSH
version: 0
'
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.SnapshotReferenceUtil$1.storeFile(SnapshotReferenceUtil.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSVisitor.visitRegionStoreFiles(FSVisitor.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSVisitor.visitTableStoreFiles(FSVisitor.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.SnapshotReferenceUtil.visitTableStoreFiles(SnapshotReferenceUtil.java:114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.SnapshotReferenceUtil.verifySnapshot(SnapshotReferenceUtil.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.snapshot.SnapshotManager.restoreSnapshot(SnapshotManager.java:713)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.restoreSnapshot(HMaster.java:3025)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:38247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2008)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FifoRpcScheduler$1.run(FifoRpcScheduler.java:73)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to open link: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.HFileLink locations=[hdfs://cluster2/apps/hbase/data/data/default/my_table/d988362b296868d458b9473126ed391e/r/0ff1b8969c3049cc9f9f9852760de544, hdfs://cluster2/apps/hbase/data/.tmp/data/default/my_table/d988362b296868d458b9473126ed391e/r/0ff1b8969c3049cc9f9f9852760de544, hdfs://cluster2/apps/hbase/data/archive/data/default/my_table/d988362b296868d458b9473126ed391e/r/0ff1b8969c3049cc9f9f9852760de544]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.FileLink.getFileStatus(FileLink.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.SnapshotReferenceUtil$1.storeFile(SnapshotReferenceUtil.java:174)
        ... 15 more
```

So what other files do I need to include in my export?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said, export creates two directories .hbase-snapshot and archive.
you need both, .hbase-snapshot is just the metadata the actual data is inside archive

Comment: Thanks! It worked after I also exported the archive.